# Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли элегантный способ обрезки структур типа java.util.Map , так чтобы в ней осталось N элементов?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли элегантный способ обрезки структур типа java.util.Map , так чтобы в ней осталось N элементов?

Comment: `map.stream().limit(N).collect(someMapCollector);`

Comment: А для Java младше 8-ой версии, где нет стримов как это сделать? :)

Comment: Получить `keySet` и итерировать.

Comment: `map.keySet().removeAll(Arrays.asList(map.keySet().toArray()).subList(0,N));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение простое

```
    Map<String, String> newMap = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .limit(100)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Для тех кто застрял в каменном веке без стримов чуть сложнее

```
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();

    int count = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> current : map.entrySet()) {
        if (count >= 100) {
            break;
        }
        newMap.put(current.getKey(), current.getValue());
        count++;
    }
```

Если хочется покалечить существующую коллекцию то можно так

```
    while (map.size() > 100) {
        String key = map.keySet().iterator().next();
        map.remove(key);
    }
```